# How to solve and see resolution of $13^{53} \pmod 7$ using Fermat little Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to solve and see resolution of $13^{53} \pmod 7$ using Fermat little Theorem? Using [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), I know it gives me 6 as an answer to this problem..., but why? How is the resolution?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure it is related somehow to `Mathematica` programming ?  Hint : for odd numbers it is always 6.

Comment: I mean $13^k \mod 7 = 6$ for all odd $k$.

Comment: Ok, thank you.. But why?.. I mean, which theorem says so..?

Comment: If this _were_ a Mathematica question the answer should be `Mod[13^53, 7]`

Comment: $13 \times 6 \mod 7  = 1$ and $13 \times 1 \mod 7 = 6$. You should complete the rest to prove this theorem.

Comment: @LeandroArielAltamirano Write $13^k$ as $(7+6)^k$ and then look at the terms... there's only one term that's not a power of $7$. Now look at that term for odd and even $k$. That should give you a clue... You can further expand that term as $(7-a)^k$ where you'll have to figure out what $a$ is, apply the same logic and you'll see that it boils down to either $-1\, \text{mod}\, 7$ or $1\, \text{mod}\, 7$, depending on whether $k$ is odd or even, giving you $6$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: I meant a _multiple_ of 7 in the first line above...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem says $x^7\equiv x\pmod{7}$. When $x\not\equiv0\pmod{7}$, we can divide by $x$ to get
$$
x^6\equiv1\pmod{7}
$$
In the case of $13^{53}$, we get that $13^{53}=13^{6\cdot8+5}=\left(13^6\right)^8\cdot13^5\equiv1^8\cdot(-1)^5\equiv-1\pmod{7}$ since $13^6\equiv1\pmod{7}$ and $13\equiv-1\pmod{7}$.

Of course, since $13\equiv-1\pmod{7}$, we get that $13^{53}\equiv(-1)^{53}\equiv-1\pmod{7}$.

In any case, $13^{53}\equiv-1\equiv6\pmod{7}$.

Comment: Ohh..., I want to be like you when I grow Up... Thank You!

Comment: @Leandro: You mean you want to be a mean square with a big bushy beard? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: only if I haven't trimmed in a long time :-p